# How to include search/filter in a table and include Pagination as well in Java SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria-api

I'm building a web app using Java Spring Boot and thymeleaf. I know how to include Pagination in this. I followed this link https://dzone.com/articles/pagingandsortingrepository-how-to-use-with-thymele

The problem now is, how do I include a search/filter form and how to include paging in the search results? 
I know I can use CriteriaBuilder (like the findBuildings() function below) to get the search results but how to incorporate paging in it?

private EntityManager em; 
    public List findBuildings(Building searchedBuilding) {

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Building> cq = cb.createQuery(Building.class);
    Root<Building> quest = cq.from(Building.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if (searchedBuilding.getAddress() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(quest.get("Address"), "%" + searchedBuilding.getAddress()+ "%"));
    }
    if (searchedBuilding.getBuildingType() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.like(quest.get("BuildingType"), "%" + searchedBuilding.getBuildingType() + "%"));
    }
    // other predicates

    cq.select(quest).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
    List<Building> buildings = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return buildings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring data (https://spring.io/projects/spring-data).

Create an repository interface, and create your query like this:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct b from Building b where b.Address like %:searchParam%")
Page<Building> search(Pageable pageable, @Param("searchParam") String searchParam);
```

You can get the Pageable interface in yout controller like this:

```
@GetMapping("/your/path/{searchParam}")
public ModelAndView getBuilding(Pageable pageable, @PathVariable String searchParam) {
    Page<Building> page = buildingRepository.search(peageable, searchParam);
    ....
    //your code here
}
```

In the url you can pass the size and the current page.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html

Comment: But I have multiple parameters. I don't want to write a query for every possible combination

Answer (score 0):

After `createQuery()`, instead to call `getResultList()` you have to do the following:

```
public List findBuildings(Building search, int firstResult, int pageSize) {

    //omitted ...

    Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
    query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    List<Building> buildings = query.getResultList();
    return buildings;
}
```

Where `firstResult` and `maxResult` are calculated.

For example if page is 1 with 50 elements each page->

`firstResult = 0`

`maxResults = 50`

Comment: That sounds reasonable but my model accepts a Page which is then being used to make the navbar. I guess I can use this and then pass pagenumber,pagesize and total numbers in the dto or something.

Comment: No you can't... but the difference is straightforward. for example let's assume you are at page 4 and you want to show 30 elements. `firstResult = 4X30-1` -1 because first element is 0, and `maxResults=30` that is exactly the size of the page

Comment: ugh my bad! I meant my view. I need at least the total number of pages to generate the page navigation links.

Comment: in your frontend you need to know the Page number selected and the total page number (calculated with a count) probably because the user can select also a specific page, but you can write an util method that calculate firstElement with maxResult to pass to `Query` object